# How to fix displaying data from service in directive unless page refreshed with angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following:

```
1 - MyService - a service that requests some data via $http
2 - MyDirective - a directive I want to show the data retrieved from the service
```

My issue is that when I first load the page, the data retrieved from MyService appears to NOT be displayed at all in the directive. When I reload the page, it shows up fine. All subsequent reloads are fine.

The sequence of events is as follows:

```
1- Service fetches "data", a promise tracking when data comes back, then broadcasts a "ready" message to the directive.
2- Directive receives the "ready" with $on and puts the "data" somewhere viewable on the directive.
```

When I go to a URL for the first time:

```
1- The directive shows up, but with none of the "data" from the service shows up.
2- Refresh the page/route
3- The directive shows up with the correct data.
```

It appears it does not show up because of the retrieval, but when I log out the $on emitters in the directive, it appears that the service has successfully received the data and it does not show up as "undefined", but is failing to actually put them into the directive... what is the issue and how could I get around it?

Notes:

```
- The $on's that check for the ready event are in the directive's "controller:". 
- The directive's "link:" calls on the directive's "controller" methods for initialization (without any data from the service, as that logic is in the $on).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you misunderstood the use of services. A Service is not loading data on itself, but is injected and the call is done by the service's caller object/controller/directive.

Though you did not post the service-code your problem seems to be, that angular is constructing the service for injection, but at this time you are already firing the `$http` call and wait for the result. When it arrives, you don't know who needs the data, as a service factory is always a **singleton**.

Following should always work, because the request is **send** when the directive was compiled and is in the linking phase. The callback is in the right place and can set the result to the scope (where you want it actually).

(*feel free to edit this.. was from my mind and not error checked*)

```
.factory('MyData', function($http) {
  var MyData = {};
  MyData.callData = function(method, url) {
    return $http(method, url);
  }
  return MyData;
})

.directive('myDirective', function(MyData) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
      MyData.callData('GET', '/something/useful')
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          $scope.items = data;
        });
    }
  }
});
```

```
<my-directive>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</li>
  </ul>
</my-directive>
```

**Update**
best way is to use http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource anyway ;) If format applies but quite a lot is configurable. Include angular-resource.js in index.html and 'ngResource' as module in your application -> this is new stuff todo since 1.2

Answer (score 0):

This is a timing problem, when the data is received and the event is fired, your directive ***may not be constructed*** yet. When you reload the page, it works because your directive template may be cached, making it ***faster*** to be constructed.

My solution to this problem is using $watch. Below is some example code:

```
app.controller('MyController',function($scope, MyService){
     //Get data here using your MyService and assign to $scope.data
});

app.directive('MyDirective', function() {

return {
   restrict: 'EA',
   controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.$watch("data",function(newValue,OldValue,scope){
             //do your work here when data is changed.
        });  
      }
   };
};
```

If you use isolate scope. Try code like this:

```
app.controller('MyController',function($scope, MyService){
         //Get data here using your MyService and assign to $scope.data
    });

    app.directive('MyDirective', function() {

    return {
       restrict: 'EA',
       scope:{
          mydata:"="
       },
       controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.$watch("mydata",function(newValue,OldValue,scope){ //listen for mydata changes
                 //do your work here when data is changed.
            });  
          }
       };
    };
```

Assign binding to html:

```
<div my-directive mydata="data"/>
```